# Identifying and removing duplicates present in column 2 when checked with column 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

| ID | ab_keywords | bc_keywords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABL345 | ryzen,ryzen 7x,ryzen 5800,ryzen 7x | ryzen,ryzen 71x,ryzen 5900,best |
| ABL448 | ryzen 5800 7x,ryzen 8x,cpu,ryzen 5800 | ryzen 5900 71x,ryzen 8x,processor,best |

This is the table, I want to identify and remove the duplicate values present in **bc_keywords***,* if those are already present in the column: **ab_keywords**

For eg: "ryzen" is present in both the columns for ID: ABL345, so i want to identify it and remove it from the **bc_keywords**

so my expected table would look something like this:

| ID | ab_keywords | bc_keywords | duplis | bc_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABL345 | ryzen,ryzen 7x,ryzen 5800,ryzen 7x | ryzen,ryzen 71x,ryzen 5900,best | ryzen | ryzen 71x,ryzen 5900,best |
| ABL448 | ryzen 5800 7x,ryzen 8x,cpu,ryzen 5800 | ryzen 5900 71x,ryzen 8x,processor,best | ryzen 8x | ryzen 5900 71x,processor,best |

Is there any way that I can do it ?
column "duplis" is also not much needed, my main objective is to remove the duplis and add the new list of keywords in a new column.

I have tried using df.duplicated(), but definitely seems like I am doing something wrong, and did not get the answer that I was looking for

df.duplicated() just gave me a boolean series column

I have also tried the following method:

```
dof['new'] = list(set(dof['bc']) - set(dof['ab']))
dof['new']
dof.head()
```

but the output seems weird:

| ID | ab_keywords | bc_keywords | bc_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABL345 | ryzen,ryzen 7x,ryzen 5800,ryzen 7x | ryzen,ryzen 71x,ryzen 5900,best | ryzen 5900 71x,ryzen 8x,processor,best |
| ABL448 | ryzen 5800 7x,ryzen 8x,cpu,ryzen 5800 | ryzen 5900 71x,ryzen 8x,processor,best | ryzen,ryzen 71x,ryzen 5900,best |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Split the `bc_keywords` column by ","
2. `explode` the column to get one row per keyword
3. Identify duplicates
4. `groupby` and `agg`-regate as needed

```
df["bc_keywords"] = df["bc_keywords"].str.split(",")
df = df.explode("bc_keywords")
duplicates = df.apply(lambda row: row["bc_keywords"] in row["ab_keywords"].split(","), axis=1)
df["bc_new"] = df["bc_keywords"].where(~duplicates)
df["duplis"] = df["bc_keywords"].where(duplicates)
output = df.groupby("ID").agg({"ab_keywords": "first", 
                               "bc_keywords": ",".join, 
                               "duplis": "first",
                               "bc_new": lambda x: ",".join(x.dropna())})

>>> output
```

| ID | ab_keywords | bc_keywords | duplis | bc_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABL345 | ryzen,ryzen 7x,ryzen 5800,ryzen 7x | ryzen,ryzen 71x,ryzen 5900,best | ryzen | ryzen 71x,ryzen 5900,best |
| ABL448 | ryzen 5800 7x,ryzen 8x,cpu,ryzen 5800 | ryzen 5900 71x,ryzen 8x,processor,best | ryzen 8x | ryzen 5900 71x,processor,best |

Comment: But can you help me with this part:  ab_keywords": "first", "duplis": "first", as in what is the "first" in here ?

Comment: @Popeye - It is to get the "first" value in the group that isn't `nan`

Answer (score 0):

You should apply this logic to each row in your dataframe.

I've created a mock dataset based on your example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "ab_keywords": ["aaa,bbb,ccc", "bbb,ccc,dd,eee"],
    "bc_keywords": ["bbb,ccc,rrr", "ccc,eee,fff,ggg"]
})
```

Then prepare a function to apply to each row:

```
def remove_duplicates(row):
    return list(set(row['bc_keywords'].split(",")) - set(row['ab_keywords'].split(",")))

data["bc_new"] = data.apply(remove_duplicates, axis=1)
data
```

Output:

```
    ab_keywords     bc_keywords     bc_new
0   aaa,bbb,ccc     bbb,ccc,rrr     [rrr]
1   bbb,ccc,dd,eee  ccc,eee,fff,ggg [fff, ggg]
```

If your values are stored as strings rather then lists, you should also split them into lists before applying the function or inside the function.

Edit: I've updated the code to deal with values as strings - added splitting them into lists first.

Comment: Hi Maria, I have tried to use your suggested code, but the output is kind of breaking each word into letters I guess, and I am getting:  0 - [1,9,s,t,b]  1 - [9,1,o,s,s,t,b]

Comment: Yeah, that means that your values are stored in strings. set(some_string) splits the string into symbols. You have to split string values into lists before creating sets. I've updated my answer, should work now.

Comment: Great! Could you please accept the answer if you're going with it?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use a *helper func* to `dedup` the keywords formed with [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) :

```
from functools import partial

def sjoin(kws, sep=","):
    return sep.join(filter(None, kws))

def dedup(lst_ab, lst_bc):
    dups, new_bc = zip(
        *[(bc, None) if bc in lst_ab else (None, bc) for bc in lst_bc]
    )
    return sjoin(dups), sjoin(new_bc) # <-- add the sep(s) if needed

keywords = df[["ab_keywords", "bc_keywords"]].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(","), axis=1)

df["duplis"], df["new_bc"] = zip(
    *[dedup(lst_ab, lst_bc) for lst_ab, lst_bc in keywords.to_numpy()]
)
```

Output :

| ID | ab_keywords | bc_keywords | duplis | new_bc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABL345 | ryzen,ryzen 7x,ryzen 5800,ryzen 7x | ryzen,ryzen 71x,ryzen 5900,best | ryzen | ryzen 71x,ryzen 5900,best |
| ABL448 | ryzen 5800 7x,ryzen 8x,cpu,ryzen 5800 | ryzen 5900 71x,ryzen 8x,processor,best | ryzen 8x | ryzen 5900 71x,processor,best |

Comment: Thank you, this code worked as well :)